# why sms not receiving with aws sns for countries like Venezuela?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send sms using aws sns service, working for many countries. but when i try with Venezuela phone number, it's not reaching destination. how can debug this issue ??

Any additional steps required for these type of countries ??

Comment: [Supported Regions and countries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html) shows Venzuela as supported. If you activate [SMS delivery status logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html#topics-attrib) then you will receive more information about why the SMS could not be delivered.